# Refresh badge of tabBar in an other view

Tags: ios, refresh, tabbar, badge

I've a tabBar controller. Is it possible to set the badge of one viewController by tapping a button in the other view?

for example...
in `viewController2` is one method.

```
-(void)newBadge{
    _badge++;
    self.navigationController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_badge];       
}
```

Is it now possible to use this method in `viewController1` and also display the badge right after tapping the button?
Thanks to all of you in advance.

Comment: Sorry...next time I'll remember it

Comment: for code it's ok, just not for emphasis, see e.g. [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
-(void)newBadge{
    _badge++;
    [[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0] setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_badge];
}
```

objectAtIndex should be the tab bar you want to set.

Comment: Thanks...but is it also possible to do this in appDelegate?